# I want to parse json, but it does not

Tags: json, qt, parsing

I want to get tmX, tmY from this json, but I can not get it.

How can I get a value?

I do not think there's anything more to write ...

```
{
   "list":[
      {
         "_returnType":"json",
         "map":"",
         "numOfRows":"10",
         "pageNo":"1",
         "tmX":"196543.111337",
         "tmY":"173653.845412"
      }
   ],
   "totalCount":1
}
```

```
QString tmX, tmY;
if (jsonObj.contains("list")) {
    QJsonObject listObj = jsonObj["list"].toObject();
    if (listObj.contains("tmX"))
        tmX = listObj["tmX"].toString();

    if (listObj.contains("tmY"))
        tmY = listObj["tmY"].toString();
}
```

Comment: List is an array, so it doesn't directly contain `tmX` and `tmY`. You want `listObj[0].contains("tmX")`, or you want a loop. Or whatever the syntax is for declaring and accessing JSON arrays in QT.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to solve the problem.